# Functional Component not receiving props from App container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to make a game and trying to render a initial turn modal and pass it props that will tell it which text content to display depending on the application's state. Currently the modal mounts but props come back as undefinied.

Here is the App container Component:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Redux from 'redux';
import Board from './components/board';
import Piece from './components/piece';
import toggleTurn from './helper/toggleTurn';
import diceRoll from './helper/diceRoll';
import TurnModal from './components/TurnModal';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      game_not_over: null,
      curr_turn: null,
      player1: {
        playerId: 1,
        pieces: [],
        score: null
      },
      player2: {
        playerId: 2,
        pieces: [],
        score: null
      }
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.startGame();
  }

  initPieces(player) {
    //Responsible for creating an array of Piece components
    let pieces = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pieces[i] = <Piece key={i} position={null} owner={player} />;
    }
    return pieces;
  }

  launchFirstTurnChoice() {
    ReactDOM.render(<TurnModal playerTurn={this.curr_turn} />, document.getElementById('root'));
  }
  
  launchTurn(playerId) {    
    const startTurnModal = <TurnModal modalmessage={"startTurnMessage"} />
    ReactDOM.render(startTurnModal, document.getElementById('root'));
    //Should display a modal that announces player turn and waits from them to press a start turn button
    //Rolls dice
    //Waits for player to select piece
    //Checks that a destination has been selected
    //Upon End Move Submission update piece position state
  }
  
  startGame() {
    console.log("Starting Game!");
    const player1 = this.state.player1;
    const player2 = this.state.player2;
    
    player1.pieces = this.initPieces();
    player2.pieces = this.initPieces();
    do {
      this.launchFirstTurnChoice();
    }
    while(this.state.game_not_over) {

    }
    
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>  
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;

const startTurnMessage = "please roll the dice to decide first turn";
```

and here is the modal component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Props needed: current turn, 

const TurnModal = (props) => {
  console.log("TurnModal mounting!")
  console.log(props.modalmessage);
  return (
    <div className="Modal">
      <center>{props.modalmessage}</center>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TurnModal;
```

Also it's fine for me to house app logic within a container component?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered I was editing a duplicate line instead of the ReactDOM.render() call I should have been editing.